# Get the value of a child input using JavaScript by its class parent

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to get the input value by the label class using Javascript, not Jquery. My html code is:

```
<label class="btn btn-secondary button-calculator">
   <input type="radio" name="units[]" id="units1" value="1" autocomplete="off"> US units
</label>

<label class="btn btn-secondary button-calculator  active">
   <input type="radio" name="units[]" id="units2" value="2" autocomplete="off" checked=""> Metric units
</label>
```

I've tried with

```
document.getElementsByClassName("active").children
```

and

```
document.getElementsByClassName("active").value
```

and checking the console.log values but i don't get anything useful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `querySelector` and/or `querySelectorAll` to target the label by class and then the input elements within the `active` labels - like so:

( 3rd input added for clarity )

```js
document.querySelectorAll('label.active input').forEach( input=>{
  input.addEventListener('click',e=>{
    console.info('Changed value: %s for %s',e.target.value,e.target.id)
  });
  
  console.info('Initial value: %s for %s',input.value,input.id)
})
```

```html
<label class="btn btn-secondary button-calculator">
   <input type="radio" name="units[]" id="units1" value="1" autocomplete="off"> US units
</label>

<label class="btn btn-secondary button-calculator  active">
   <input type="radio" name="units[]" id="units2" value="2" autocomplete="off" checked=""> Metric units
</label>

<label class="btn btn-secondary button-calculator  active">
   <input type="radio" name="units[]" id="units3" value="3" autocomplete="off"/> Imperial units
</label>
```

Answer (score 5):

First of all, since you're using `getElementsByClassName` as your initial selector, you will receive a collection of elements. If you're sure that in your whole page there's only one element with that class, you can access it with `[0]` otherwise you need to `loop` the element.

In code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("active")[0]
```

Now that you have your label element, you can retrieve all the child nodes with `childNodes`. To only retrieve the `input` based on your current HTML code, you can use `querySelector('input')`

In code

```
document.getElementsByClassName("active")[0].querySelector('input[name="units[]"]')
```

The above code might cause issues if you use the `active` class anywhere else in your page. And since the `active` class is quite common, you might want to be more specific with your selector.

My suggestion would be to use the `button-calculator` class together with the `active` class.

So in code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("active button-calculator")[0].querySelector('input[name="units[]"]')
```

Answer (score 2):

In case of child elements, you need to select elements of the parent instead of document.

```js
let labels = document.querySelectorAll(".button-calculator");
let input1 = labels[0].querySelector("input").value;
let input2 = labels[1].querySelector("input").value;

console.log(`Input 1: ${input1}`)
console.log(`input 2: ${input2}`);
```

```html
<label class="btn btn-secondary button-calculator">
   <input type="radio" name="units[]" id="units1" value="1" autocomplete="off"> US units
</label>

<label class="btn btn-secondary button-calculator  active">
   <input type="radio" name="units[]" id="units2" value="2" autocomplete="off" checked=""> Metric units
</label>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to take in consideration the `active` class, which I believe is what OP was going for unless I misunderstood something in the question

Answer (score 2):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) will retrieve an *array-like* live nodelist of elements - array-like because it looks like an array but it doesn't have access to the majority of the [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) methods.

Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to grab all the active elements. Then you can coerce that to an array (`Array.from(nodelist)` or `[...nodelist]`) and [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over it returning the values of the inputs as an array of integers.

```js
const active = document.querySelectorAll('.active');

const values = [...active].map(a => {
  return +a.querySelector('input').value;
});

console.log(values);
```

```html
<label>
<input type="radio" name="units[]" value="1">US units</input>
</label>
<label class="active">
   <input type="radio" name="units[]" value="2" checked>Metric units</input>
</label>
<label>
<input type="radio" name="units2[]" value="1">Things</input>
</label>
<label class="active">
   <input type="radio" name="units2[]" value="5" checked>Other things</input>
</label>
```